# How to get .net core 2.1 mvc web application debugged on a remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the default .net core 2.1 MVC application open with build mode set to debug. It is being hosted on IIS Server running on windows server 2016.

I publish the solution to a mapped network drive of a remote server with configuration set to debug from visual studio. When I connect to the "w3___" process it open's up a debug session but all breakpoints have the following message and don't get hit:

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

Please advise on how to get breakpoints working.

Comment: What kind of remote server, Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows Server 2016

Comment: Then how did you set up remote debugging? Did you install Visual Studio remote debugger on that remote server?

Comment: Yes I installed remote debugger on the server and then I attach to the w3... process

Comment: You attached to the wrong process, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1

Comment: That's because you don't really know the differences between "ASP.NET" and "ASP.NET Core".

Comment: I believe I wrote it clearly in my blog post.

Comment: Thank you - that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those still wondering about this, the question was answered by @Lex Li. For .net core you need to attatch to dotnet.exe rather than the w3 process.